# Docker wordpress container with two volumes on separate domains

Tags: wordpress, git, docker, docker-compose

Okay, so I have a docker compose file, that sets up a WP container, with external wp-content folder served on a domain.

Can I set up two separate volumes to be served on separate domains?

Thinking about dev and production on separate domains with separate files, but using only one container?

Comment: Please post more details, e.g. your `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml`. But do you have a reason against using a second container?

Comment: That is what I realised, after having a good sleep over it. It's easier to set up a dev image with the dev location of the files than bothering with one image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as mgansler suggested, Use of two separate image is more efficient, as I can destroy the dev image as soon as I have finished with the dev work.